# Sass maven plugin with compass fails for multi-module project

Tags: maven, sass, maven-3

I have a multi-module maven project with a child module that is uses the sass-maven-plugin. The problem is that everything works fine when running from the child module, but when running the entire project from the root the sass plugin fails.

Project setup:

```
+-- parent (pom.xml)
   +--- child-module-1 (pom.xml)
   +--- child-module-2 (pom.xml)
```

The child-module-1 uses the sass-maven-plugin.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jasig.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sass-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <useCompass>true</useCompass>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <source>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/skin/sass</directory>
                    </source>
                    <destination>${project.build.directory}/skin/stylesheets</destination>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>update-stylesheets</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

As mentioned it works when running mvn install directly from the child, but when running from the parent I get the following error from the child:

```
[ERROR] Compilation of template 
/parent/child-module-1/target/skin/sass/style.scss failed:
No files were found in the load path matching "uskin/*.png". 
Your current load paths are: ./images
```

It seems that the problem is that config.rb, which is located in the child module, is not found when running from the parent.

This problem is similar to the one specified here: https://github.com/Jasig/sass-maven-plugin/issues/43